# SQL: Return "true" if list of records exists?

Tags: sql, boolean, conditional-statements, exists

An alternative title might be:
Check for existence of multiple rows?

Using a combination of SQL and C# I want a method to return true if all products in a list exist in a table.  If it can be done all in SQL that would be preferable.  I have written a method that returns whether a single `productID` exists using the following SQL:

```
SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @productID
```

If this returns a row, then the c# method returns true, false otherwise.

Now I'm wondering if I have a list of product IDs (not a huge list mind you, normally under 20).  How can I write a query that will return a row if all the product id's exist and no row if one or more product id's does not exist?

```
(Maybe something involving "IN" like:
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN ('1', '10', '100', 'ABC'))
```

**EDIT:**

How the result is expressed is not important to me.  Whether the query returns a `1` or `0`, an empty resultset or a non-empty one, true or false doesn't matter.  I'd prefer the answer that is 1) easy to read and understand and 2) performant

I was envisioning concatenating the list of product id's with the SQL.  Obviously this opens the code up to SQL injection (the product id's are actually `varchar`.  in this case the chance is slim but still want to avoid that possibility).  So if there is a way around this that would be better.  Using SQL Server 2005.

Product ID's are `varchar`

Comment: Are you willing to write the list of products to a temp table or some other enumerable list?

Comment: "How can I write a query that will return a row if all the product id's exist and no row if one or more product id's does not exist?" <-- is this really a row? a row(s)?  If it is row(singular), what is the row's content, does it randomly choose from products table?

Comment: I think his C# function is using `if(result.hasrows()) return true else return false`

Comment: Really I just need someway to know the whether they all exist or not.  How that's expressed doesn't really matter to me.  I assumed that an empty result set vs a non-empty one is the easiest way.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Given your updated question, these are the simplest forms:

If `ProductID` is unique you want

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN (1, 10, 100)
```

and then check that result against `3`, the number of products you're querying (this last part can be done in SQL, but it may be easier to do it in C# unless you're doing even more in SQL).

If `ProductID` is not unique it is

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN (1, 10, 100)
```

---

When the question was thought to require returning rows when all `ProductIds` are present and none otherwise:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN (1, 10, 100) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN (1, 10, 100))=3)
```

or

```
SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN (1, 10, 100) AND ((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN (1, 10, 100))=3)
```

if you actually intend to do something with the results. Otherwise the simple `SELECT 1 WHERE (SELECT ...)=3` will do as other answers have stated or implied.

Comment: That's not correct if you will adhere faithfully with the requirement `How can I write a query that will return a row if all the product id's exist and no row if one or more product id's does not exist?`, your answer will always return a row.  Anyway, the logic of requiring to return `no row` eludes me, maybe User don't want to touch the code `if (result.hasRows())`.  If for simplicity-sake, i'll use your answer.  If performance is sought after, just testing data existence (using EXISTS) is faster and nicely do the job

Comment: So many different answers but ultimately this is the path I chose.  Actually the harder part was parameterizing the "IN" list.  I did this using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause

Comment: I hadn't noticed IN clauses couldn't be parameterised before. I would go for a temporary table.

Comment: How would you dynamically build the temporary table in a parameterized way?

Comment: Do it (`CREATE TABLE #TempTable(ProductID VARCHAR(33) NOT NULL)` and many `INSERT INTO #TempTable(ProductID)VALUES(@ProductID)`) in separate parameterised queries **on the same connection** as the final query.

Comment: Just confirming my approach [described above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862080/sql-return-true-if-list-of-records-exists/2862117#comment2943319_2862117) corresponds to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/337907/256431) to the above mentioned question.

Answer (score 42):

Here's how I usually do it:

Just **replace** your query with this statement `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1`

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1
    )
    THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
END
```

Comment: On postgres at least, this can be simplified to: `SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 )`

Comment: Does it make any difference if we use `SELECT 1 FROM` instead of `SELECT * FROM`?

Answer (score 13):

@Mark Hurd, thanks for pointing out the error.

this will work (if you are using Postgresql, Sql Server 2008):

```
create table products
(
product_id int not null
);



insert into products values(1),(2),(10),(100);

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
             SELECT 1 
             FROM (values(1),(10),(100)) as x(id) 
             WHERE x.id NOT IN (select product_id from products))
        THEN 0 --'NOT ALL'

        ELSE 1 -- 'ALL'
    END
```

If you are using MySQL, make a temporary memory table(then populate 1,10,100 there):

```
create table product_memory(product_id int) engine=MEMORY;

insert into product_memory values(1),(10),(100);

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
             SELECT 1 
             FROM product_memory
             WHERE product_memory.id NOT IN (select product_id from products))
        THEN 0 -- 'NOT ALL'

        ELSE 1 -- 'ALL'
    END
```

On your C# code:

```
bool isAllExist = (int)(new SqlCommand(queryHere).ExecuteScalar()) == 1;
```

**[EDIT]**

> How can I write a query that will
>   return a row if all the product id's
>   exist and no row if one or more
>   product id's does not exist?

Regarding, returning a row(singular) if all rows exists, and **no row** to be returned if one or more product id does not exists:

MySql:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
             FROM product_memory
             WHERE product_memory.id NOT IN (select product_id from products) )
```

Posgresql, Sql Server 2008:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(            
        SELECT 1 
        FROM (values(1),(10),(100)) as x(id) 
        WHERE x.id NOT IN (select product_id from products) )
```

Then on your C# code:

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(queryhere, connectionhere);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
    return true; 
else 
    return false;
```

Or just make the condition shorter:

```
return dt.Rows.Count > 0;
```

Comment: I feel compelled to point out... the OP asked for no row if all the rows do not exist. Your solution will return a row regardless :)

Comment: yeah that's confusing :-)  even me I don't know what does that row contains, that's why I ask in OP's question what is the content of row. I think it's better to just return a row containing a boolean field and evaluate it on front-end :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [SELECT CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) statement like so:

```sql
select case when EXISTS (
 select 1 
 from <table>
 where <condition>
 ) then TRUE else FALSE end
```

It returns `TRUE` when your query in the parents exists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, the boolean type doesn't exist, but the bit type does, which can hold only 0 or 1 where 0 represents False, and 1 represents True.

I would go this way:

```
select 1
    from Products
    where ProductId IN (1, 10, 100)
```

*Here, a null or no row will be returned (if no row exists).*

Or even:

```
select case when EXISTS (
    select 1
        from Products
        where ProductId IN (1, 10, 100)
    ) then 1 else 0 end as [ProductExists]
```

*Here, either of the scalar values 1 or 0 will always be returned (if no row exists).*

Comment: I don't think this works.  In the above example if product ID's 1 and 100 exist but 10 does not, a row will still be returned

Comment: I just read your edit, and this was not what I had understood on the first place. Do you want or not to know what product doesn't exist? Do you want to know how many products don't exist? What do you want exactly?

Comment: Fyi I did not down vote you, but I think the first statement in my question sums it up pretty good. "Using a combination of SQL and C# I want a method to return true if all products in a list exist in a table"

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @values TABLE (ProductId int)
INSERT @values (1)
INSERT @values (10)
INSERT @values (100)

SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @values v) = 
                 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products p WHERE p.ProductId IN
                       (SELECT v.ProductId FROM @values v))
            THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
            ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
       END [AreAllFound]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I think this will help anyone else who comes looking...

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(ProductID) AS bit) AS [EXISTS] FROM Products WHERE(ProductID = @ProductID)
```

This will ALWAYS return TRUE if exists and FALSE if it doesn't (as opposed to no row).

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 FROM (
  SELECT 1 FROM $table WHERE $condition LIMIT 1
) AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

Your c# will have to do just a bit of work (counting the number of IDs passed in), but try this:

```
select (select count(*) from players where productid in (1, 10, 100, 1000)) = 4
```

Edit:

4 can definitely be parameterized, as can the list of integers.

If you're not generating the SQL from string input by the user, you don't need to worry about attacks. If you are, you just have to make sure you only get integers. For example, if you were taking in the string "1, 2, 3, 4", you'd do something like

```
String.Join(",", input.Split(",").Select(s => Int32.Parse(s).ToString()))
```

That will throw if you get the wrong thing. Then just set that as a parameter.

Also, be sure be sure to special case if items.Count == 0, since your DB will choke if you send it `where ParameterID in ()`.

Comment: I tested this on MySQL, and it works. You might need `select if` on MS SQL.

Comment: This is my favorite so far for succinctness.  1) Can the "4" in the above example be parameterized?  2) I need to build the product list dynamically, how can I avoid an SQL injection attack (with varchar productid's)?

Comment: @User Edited to answer those. Also, if you have any issues with SQL Server (not sure which DB you're using), check out Alec's answer, which is very similar.

Comment: I can't parse the strings as integers because the product IDs (sorry misleading name) are not integers but varchar

Comment: Parameterizing will still prevent injection

Comment: How do you parameterize an IN list?

Answer (score 0):

```
// not familiar with C#, but C#'s equivalent of PHP's:
$count = count($productIds); // where $productIds is the array you also use in IN (...)

SELECT IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN (1, 10, 100)) = $count, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the IN clause is a parameter (either to SP or hot-built SQL), then this can always be done:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM product_a
         WHERE product_id IN (1, 8, 100)
       ) = (number of commas in product_id as constant)
```

If the IN clause is a table, then this can always be done:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM product_a
         WHERE product_id IN (SELECT Products
                                FROM #WorkTable)
       ) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM #WorkTable)
```

If the IN clause is complex then either spool it into a table or write it twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IDs stored in a temp table (which can be done by some C# function or simple SQL) then the problem becomes easy and doable in SQL.

```
select "all exist"
where (select case  when count(distinct t.id) = (select count(distinct id) from #products) then "true" else "false" end
    from ProductTable t, #products p
    where t.id = p.id) = "true"
```

This will return "all exists" when all the products in `#products` exist in the target table (`ProductTable`) and will not return a row if the above is not true.

If you are not willing to write to a temp table, then you need to feed in some parameter for the number of products you are attempting to find, and replace the temp table with an 'in'; clause so the subquery looks like this:

```
SELECT "All Exist"
WHERE(
        SELECT case when count(distinct t.id) = @ProductCount then "true" else "false" 
        FROM ProductTable t 
        WHERE t.id in (1,100,10,20) -- example IDs
) = "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, I would create a stored procedure which takes [a table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).  The query should then be of a particularly simple form:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CheckAll 
    (@param dbo.ProductTableType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(1 AS bit) AS Result
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) FROM @param)
        = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) FROM @param AS p
           INNER JOIN Products 
               ON p.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
END
```

I changed this to return a row, as you seem to require.  There are other ways to do this with a WHERE NOT EXISTS (LEFT JOIN in here WHERE rhs IS NULL):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CheckAll 
    (@param dbo.ProductTableType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(1 AS bit) AS Result
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM @param AS p
        LEFT JOIN Products 
            ON p.ProductID = Products.ProductID
        WHERE Products.ProductID IS NULL
    )
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is this list of products that you're trying to determine the existence of? If that list exists within another table you could do this

```
declare @are_equal bit
declare @products int

SELECT @products = 
     count(pl.id)
FROM ProductList pl
JOIN Products p
ON pl.productId = p.productId

select @are_equal = @products == select count(id) from ProductList
```

Edit:

Then do ALL the work in C#. Cache the actual list of products in your application somewhere, and do a LINQ query.

```
var compareProducts = new List<Product>(){p1,p2,p3,p4,p5};
var found = From p in GetAllProducts()
            Join cp in compareProducts on cp.Id equals p.Id
            select p;

return compareProducts.Count == found.Count;
```

This prevents constructing SQL queries by hand, and keeps all your application logic in the application.

Comment: I will be passing the list to the C# method.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too simple, but I always use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)>0 FROM `table` WHERE condition;
```

Comment: This is not acceptable on MS SQL Server as a syntax. Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
SELECT iif(count(id)=0,'false','true') FROM table WHERE id = 19
```

Comment: Did you mean `if` instead of `iif`?

Comment: No, I mean iif  > no need for if in this case, just return true or false https://database.guide/sql-server-if-vs-iif-whats-the-difference/